# Android studio run configuration shows error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-studio-2.1

When i am setting "compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'" as SDK Version at that time module name have a cross ( x ) sign over the android icon. Inside run configuration dialog it shows error like **'Error Please select Android SDK'**. Due to that error app was not launch.

But When i am setting "compileSdkVersion 23" as SDK Version at that time every thing works fine and also app was launch.

Answer (score 0):

First confirm that you have already downloaded the sdk "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23" From SdkManager. If it is there then check the paths.

Comment: Yes i have already downloaded "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23" sdk from SDKManager and also verified sdk path.

Comment: Then set Google sdk from the module settings -> select compile sdk version from "Properties" tab on app module.

Comment: I have also tried that solution but it was not works.

Comment: Then restart the android studio.

Comment: Replace your line with
compileSdkVersion 'Google Apis:Google Apis:23'